# Kendo UI window close/minimize/maximize does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

It appears that my Kendo UI window feature to allow for close, minimize or maximize does not work at all.

I can resize, and expand it using drag, but clicking on either of the 3 buttons icons does not work.

Here is my basic setup on the cshtml file

```html
@{Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("window")
    .Title("Update user")
    .Actions(actions => actions
        //.Custom("custom")
          .Minimize()
          .Maximize()
          .Close()
      )
    .Content(@<text>
                fun sample
       
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(600)
    .Visible(false)
   .Modal(true)
  .Render();
  }
```

All other Kendo UI features work, such as tabstrip and grid.

Is there a possibility of crippleware being applied to the current Kendo app I am using?

According to the Telerik site for the account I am using, the DevCraft Complete license has expired.

Or is it the case of not importing the correct kendo links in the _layout.cshtml page?

Many thanks for your help,

RC

Comment: This has been resolved. I had to copy the latest version of jquery in the Scripts folder.